# GWT requestFactory + editor framework reloading associated entity

Tags: gwt, gwt2, requestfactory, gwt-editors

I am using GWT 2.5rc1 with RequestFactory and the Editor framework. When I save an entity with an associated model, the server's `Locator` reloads the associated model before saving. Thus, any changes in the client are over-written. For example:

```
@ProxyFor(value=Foo.class, locator=FooLocator.class)
public interface FooProxy extends EntityProxy {
  void setBar(BarProxy bar);
  BarProxy getBar();

}

@ProxyFor(value=Bar.class, locator=BarLocator.class)
public interface BarProxy interface EntityProxy {
  ...
}

// The save method implemented in an Activity.
// Invoked when the editor's save button is clicked.
public void onSave() {
  // driver is a RequestFactoryEditorDriver
  FooRequest request = (FooRequest) driver.flush();
  request.save(entity).fire(myReceiver);
}

// The service on the server that saves the two entities.
public class FooService {

  public Foo save(Foo foo) {
    barDao.save(foo.getBar()); // Bar has been reloaded via the BarLocator and all changes lost
    fooDao.save(foo);
    return foo;
  }
}
```

On the server, the `BarLocator.find(...)` method is called which reloads the Bar instance and overwrites any changes made on the incoming Bar instance.

Sample log output:

```
FooLocator loading Foo
setBar called
BarLocator loading Bar
save called
```

The last three lines all refer to the Bar that was loaded from the DB; I never see the changed Bar in any of my locator or service code.

Comment: Do you have a `setBar` on `Foo`?

Comment: I have been playing with this some more. Should FooLocator.find() return a fully hyrdated Foo? In other words, should Bar be present? The current implementation of FooLocator.find returns Foo with Bar set. The problem is on save(), FooLocator calls setBar().

Comment: When you send 2 objects to the server (foo and bar), it'll `find` them both (or `create` for a `ValueProxy`), call the property setters (including `setBar` here) and then only call service methods; so `foo.getBar()` should get your the `Bar` you loaded from the `Locator`, provided the getter/setter are simple accessors for a field.

Comment: So am I not able to save an object graph?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that your code should work. But there are many reasons it could fail (not using open-session-in-view pattern, doing more than just assigning to a field in the setters, etc.)

Comment: What do you mean by "doing more than just assigning to a field in the setters?" In setBar(...) of the actual model, there is some extra logic to check for null and also to call setBarId(bar.getId()).

Comment: Back to your question: “overwrites any changes made on the incoming Bar instance” that part should not happen. Please double-check. It should load Foo and Bar (in any order), apply changes to Foo and Bar (in any order, including calling `setBar` *before* applying changes to Bar), then call save(), where `foo.getBar` should be the Bar loaded from the locator, with the changes applied.

Comment: I double checked, everything appears correct. I decided to try reverting to 2.4 since this did work at one point. Sure enough, works in 2.4. I took a look at the issue tracker and didnt see any relavent issues opened. If you dont know of any possible existing issues filed, I will open a new one.

Comment: “everything appears correct”: so does it work? (it's a rhetorical question) Setting breakpoints (or log) in the locators' `find`, `Foo`'s `setBar`, `Bar`'s setters and `save`, are they called in the _right_ order? (described above) on the right instances? (the `Bar` loaded from the locator, not the one from `Foo`) Which `Bar` is returned by `foo.getBar()` in `save`? I still don't understand what issue you're experiencing (other than "it doesn't work")

Comment: The issue is that the Bar I receive in the save() method is not in the state that the UI sent it. The state is equal to how the BarLocator loaded it (from the DB). I updated the question with some sample log output.

Comment: did you find solution? i got same problem when i moved from gwt 2.4 to 2.5

Comment: Nope. I reverted back to 2.4 for now. I havent opened a bug because I havent had time to simplify the repro steps.